# Default filter type for resize in magick++ api

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, magick++

I am trying to resize images using Magick++ api in C++. I have used the following code and it is working good.

```
Image second = image;
Geometry newSize = Geometry(69,69);
// Resize without preserving Aspect Ratio
newSize.aspect(true);
second.resize(newSize);
```

The result  is good but I need to know the default filter type it is using as I am not giving any other argument in resize() function. I have searched in documentation but could not find much. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In MagickCore libary, the `ReszieImage` method [does default to `LanczosFilter`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/resize.c#L2868).

> From `MagickCore/resize.c`
>
> ```
> filter_type=LanczosFilter;
> if (filter != UndefinedFilter)
>     filter_type=filter;
> ```

However in `Magick++` the default filterType is [`UndefinedFilter`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/resample.h#L34). Take the following..

```cpp
Magick::Image image("rose:");
std::cout << image.filterType() << std::endl;
//=> 0
```

IMHO, always define the filter with `Magick::image::filterType( const Magick::FilterTypes filterType_ )`. It'll help when your reading the code in the future.

Comment: Can you tell me what does UndefinedFilter means?

Comment: The `UndefinedFilter` simply means that your application code has not defined a `FilterType`. In ImageMagick, the `Undefined` prefix is used to standardize the first (0) item in enumerators

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer to my own question. It was [Lanczos resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling). 
A very good [magick++ documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) can be found here.